# Release action stuck in "Pending" status for hours

Tags: ms-release-management

I have tried a release using webdeploy and release management for visual studio 2013. Configured the release based on the steps in http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/webdeploy-and-release-management--the-proper-way .
When i started release, it is showing "Pending" status for hours. Don't know what is happening. How i can find the real issue behind this? Is there any detailed log or any debugging methods in release management..??
I am new to release management, please help me....!!!!

Comment: This is not an issue specific to web deploy -- it's an issue with the deployer communicating with RM. Have you ever had a successful deployment using RM to this server before?

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the response. I successfully deployed earlier with xcopy deployer in RM client. But when i tried webdeploy this issue is happening. After that even xcopy is not working...!!

Comment: Try restarting the deployment agent service ("Microsoft Deployment Agent") on the target server, as well as the Release Management Monitor service on the RM server.

Comment: Already restarted "Microsoft Deployment Agent" but no use. Will restart  "Release Management Monitor service" and will see... thanks @DanielMann

Comment: When i restarted "Release Management Monitor" service, it was showing my license expired..!! I wasted my time on this issue. I have installed a licensed version, will check same scenario and will  update you gays..!!

Comment: @DanielMann I restarted "Release Management Monitor service", then only it was showing my license expired. Already reinstalled it, will try this once again and will update you guys.. Thanks for the responses...!

Comment: Check the Event Log on the RM server. When I had this problem, there were constant errors with a source of "Release Management Services"

Answer (score 2):

My RM license was expired and it was not showing any warning messages on the expiration. When i restarted "Release Management Monitor" service, it was showing license expired..!!!

I reinstalled RM and the issue has been resolved...!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue, then I solved it removing all items from Release Template and adding them back afterwards.

Posted here about: 
https://fabiostawinski.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/release-management-stuck-on-pending-statusbug/

Answer (score 0):

For me, @DanielMann 's comment about restarting the Microsoft Deployment Agent service on the target server was the solution.